# Recursing based on a list of pandas Series values

Tags: python, pandas, recursion

Firstly I have to apologize if my question is a little vague. It is a simplified version of a longer problem. Using a toy example, I have a recursive function defined as such:

```
Recur(x,z):
    if stopping criterion: 
      ...
    else:
        S = (some output in pd.Series type)
        if S == 0:
            return Recur(x,z)
        else:
            return Recur(y,z)
```

Basically S contains a pandas series of 1's and 0's. And depending on whether the ith element of S is a 1 or a 0 the appropriate recursion is executed. This whole recursion tree is repeated for each element in S. Running this function gives the following error:

```
  *File "<ipython-input-92-05fb4b8bad66>", line 12, in Recur
    if split_feature_value == 0:
  File "C:\Users\dp\Anaconda3_2.5.0\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 731, in __nonzero__.format(self.__class__.__name__))*

*ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().*
```

Ideally I would like to use this as a lambda function that I can apply to DataFrames, so I reckon indexing as a potential fix is out of the question.

Can I get some help getting this to work please?

Answer (score 0):

try to compare it in the following way:

```
In [227]: S = pd.Series([0,0,0,0,0,0])

In [228]: (S == 0).all()
Out[228]: True

In [229]: S[1] = 1

In [230]: S
Out[230]:
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    0
dtype: int64

In [231]: (S == 0).all()
Out[231]: False
```

Comment: I'm so sorry if I wasn't clear earlier. I think my problem is closer to this: if S == 0: func(). So if S = pd.Series([0,0,0]), func() would be called 3 times. I get the same error as per my original question.

Comment: @beginner, basically you don't want to loop or to do recursion through your pandas DFs, you want to work with vectorized data sets. I would suggest you to provide a small input data set (5-7 rows), explain what do you want to do with this data set and provide an expected output. This way SO community will be able (hopefully) to provide you the most efficient/elegant way to do that. Please provide all data sets in __text__ format, otherwise it's not possible to copy and paste them for developing a solution